# GORM CriteriaBuilder sqlRestriction CONTAINS clause

Tags: grails, grails-orm, contains

I am trying to use a GORM CriteriaBuilder to do a full text search on a SQL Server database using the CONTAINS clause on a field name.  I am trying to use the sqlRestriction method to do this.  Also, the CriteriaBuilder may contain a number of other optional criteria.

Something like:

```
Table.createCriteria.list {
    and {
      if (option1) { eq "field1", option1 }
      if (option2) { like "field2", option2 }
      if (option3) { sqlRestriction "CONTAINS(field3, '${option3}')" }
    }
}
```

option3 can contain boolean operators.

Has anyone been successful with this?

Unit testing throws exception on sqlRestriction line:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder.sqlRestriction() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String)

I thought that a String type was exactly what sqlRestriction is looking for.

Open to alternatives.  Thanks in advance.

Using grails 2.0.3.

Comment: Everything looks ok according to the docs - a string seems to be what it expects.  Quick question: is field3 the actual name of the database column, not you domain element?

Comment: with sqlRestriction, 'field3' should be the db field name, not the domain property name.

Comment: After more development, it turns out that the code works as expected when running as a web app.  However, neither unit nor integration tests work with the 'CONTAINS' in the sqlRestriction.  I would not expect the unit test to work since the 'CONTAINS' clause is SQL Server specific.  But, I expect it to work within an integration test.

Comment: Good to know - as far as 'field3' being the db field name that is what I was trying to say: that is should be the field name, not the domain property name.

Comment: you need to use plasticCriteria plugin